# Type Mismatch when placing Excel cell info in SAP field

Tags: excel, vba, loops, declare

I am working on a scrip that creates Sales Orders in SAP's VA01 - Order Creation, DEP - Production environment.

All of the information is drawn from the Excel file where the macro is stored. These are the two issues I am facing at the moment:

1. If I declare variables I get the Run-time error 13: mismatch error in the very beginning of the code.

I solved this by typing directly into the script the type of order I am creating at the moment. However, I would like to declare the variables for these as the type may change in the future. I attempted to use the variables declared, and also a cell reference. The script leaves the fields in blank.

Here is that section of the script:

```
'Order creation set up
session.StartTransaction "va01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = "YKE" 'ws.Cells(3, 14).Value 'OrderType
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKORG").Text = "CE01" 'ws.Cells(4, 14).Value 'SalesOrg
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VTWEG").Text = "10" 'ws.Cells(5, 14).Value 'DistChan
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").Text = "10"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

2. I get the Run-time error 619: control could not be found by ID.

This happens in this section of the script, precisely in the line Condition and ConditionVal:

```
'Entering the header for the Condition Type and Condition Type Value
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").SetFocus
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/subSUBSCREEN_PUSHBUTTONS:SAPLV69A:1000/btnBT_KOAN").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/ctxtKOMV-KSCHL[1,1]").Text = Condition 'ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").Text = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value 'ConditionVal
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").caretPosition = 16
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
```

To me it does not make sense, as in a previous section of the script the variables were declared and used without inconvenients. For what I gather, the issues here are the variables declarations.

When I use the variables declared the fields again stay blank.

I have tried using Long, String, and Variants, however no luck. Can someone suggest an option? Has someone faced this issue in the past and managed to overcome it?

Here is the full code, as well as a print screen of the Excel file for references:

```
Sub BROrderCreation()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim maxi As String
Dim lastRow As Long

'On Error GoTo PopUpHandler

  Set GuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
  Set App = GuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
  Set Con = App.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
  Set session = Con.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
  Set sessioninfo = session.Info

'Declare variables for the order type, sales organization, distribution chanel and division
Dim OrderType As String
Dim SalesOrg As String
Dim DistChan As Byte
Dim Div As Byte

Set ws = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PO Data")
OrderType = ws.Cells(3, 14).Value
SalesOrg = ws.Cells(4, 14).Value
DistChan = ws.Cells(5, 14).Value
Div = ws.Cells(6, 14).Value

'Order creation set up
session.StartTransaction "va01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = "YKE" 'ws.Cells(3, 14).Value 'OrderType
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKORG").Text = "CE01" 'ws.Cells(4, 14).Value 'SalesOrg
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VTWEG").Text = "10" 'ws.Cells(5, 14).Value 'DistChan
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").Text = "10"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

i = 2
maxi = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do While i < maxi + 1

'Declare variables for Ship To, PO, RDD, SKU, QTY, Plant, Batch, Condition and Condition Value
Dim ShipTo As Variant
Dim PO As Variant
Dim RDD As Variant
Dim SKU As String
Dim QTY As String
Dim Plant As Variant
Dim Batch As Variant
Dim Condition As String
Dim ConditionVal As String

ShipTo = Cells(i, 1).Value
PO = Cells(i, 2).Value
RDD = Cells(i, 3).Value
SKU = Cells(i, 4).Value
QTY = Cells(i, 5).Value
Plant = Cells(i, 6).Value
Batch = Cells(i, 7).Value
Condition = Cells(i, 10).Value
ConditionVal = Cells(i, 11).Value

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/txtVBKD-BSTKD").Text = PO
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/subPART-SUB:SAPMV45A:4701/ctxtKUWEV-KUNNR").Text = ShipTo
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/ctxtRV45A-KETDAT").Text = RDD
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").Text = SKU
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,0]").Text = QTY
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtVBAP-WERKS[3,0]").Text = Plant
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtVBAP-CHARG[9,0]").Text = Batch
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtVBAP-CHARG[9,0]").SetFocus
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtVBAP-CHARG[9,0]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 'To cover the process in case the PO is already created


'Entering the header for the Condition Type and Condition Type Value
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").SetFocus
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/subSUBSCREEN_PUSHBUTTONS:SAPLV69A:1000/btnBT_KOAN").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/ctxtKOMV-KSCHL[1,1]").Text = Condition 'ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").Text = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value 'ConditionVal
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,1]").caretPosition = 16
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

'ZDEF screen accept and click on Invalid destination
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnZACCEPT").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Cells(i, 11) = "Placed"

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of the Excel File]

Comment: you have `Condition = Cells(i, 10).Value` but column 10 is J NSVSAP? Condition is column L (12)

Comment: Hi CDP, thanks for that. That solved the 2nd issue of the script! I totally missed it. I was too focused into finding an issue with the variable declaration. Do you have any advice for the 1st problem?

Comment: `Dim maxi As String` looks odd for a row number

Comment: Try changing these to String `Dim DistChan As Byte
Dim Div As Byte`